# Qt4: How to detect when a QAction shortcut key is released

Tags: qt, qt4, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to display something on the screen as long as a certain key combination is pressed (using Qt4.x). It has to be an configurable application-wide shortcut, so I'd like to do this with a QAction with an attached shortcut.
The problem is that there seems to be no way to detect when the user releases the shortcut. I tried with a one-shot timer, in combination with the auto-repeat option, but this is unreliable and there is a delay before the hide-method is called.

Answer (score 4):

Using the shortcut mechanism provided by Qt, you can only react to the key combination being [activated](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qshortcut.html#activated).

Why do you need to detec the key release ? If you need it, maybe you'll have to do reimplement the [keyPressEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) and [keyReleaseEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#keyReleaseEvent) functions, but before that, I would think twice if detecting the key release is really needed.

Comment: The idea is to show a navigation HUD only when the user presses the shortcut. Once released, it is hidden again. 

Implementing keyPress/ReleaseEvent is an option, but I'd like to let the shortcut be application-wide, not depending on the current focus.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `QShortcut` won't work for what you'd like to do though, although I've never done any HUD thing with Qt. I would stick to the keyPressEvent and keyReleaseEvent idea, using an [event filter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to have an application wide key detection.

Comment: You could also look into doing the detection as an event filter that you put on your application window, or on the QApplication object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a keyboard shortcut you should use [QShortcut](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qshortcut.html) instead.